# Loop through get_posts to create a nested multidimensional array and JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have an issue with this wp_query function. I need to create a nested JSON like so:

```json
{
    "country_zone A": [
        {
            "tarif_zone A": {
                "out": "0.0",
                "in": "0.2",
                "data": "1"
            },
            "tarif_zone B": {
                "out": "0.0",
                "in": "0.2",
                "data": "1"
            },
            " tarif_zoneC": {
                "out": "0.0",
                "in": "0.2",
                "data": "1"
            },
            "tarif_zone D": {
                "out": "0.0",
                "in": "0.2",
                "data": "1"
            }
        }
    ],
    " country_zone B": [
        {
            "tarif_zone A ": {
                "out": "0.0",
                "in": "0.2",
                "data": "1"
            },
            "tarif_zone B": {
                "out": "0.0",
                "in": "0.2",
                "data": "1"
            },
            "tarif_zone C": {
                "out": "0.0",
                "in": "0.2",
                "data": "1"
            },
            "tarif_zone D": {
                "out": "0.0",
                "in": "0.2",
                "data": "1"
            }
        }
    ],
    "country_zone C": [
        {
            " tarif_zone A": {
                "out": "0.0",
                "in": "0.2",
                "data": "1"
            },
            "tarif_zone B": {
                "out": "0.0",
                "in": "0.2",
                "data": "1"
            },
            "tarif_zone C": {
                "out": "0.0",
                "in": "0.2",
                "data": "1"
            },
            "tarif_zone D": {
                "out": "0.0",
                "in": "0.2",
                "data": "1"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have ACF Fields that correspond to these fields and I need this JSON to retrieve data in the JS frontend.

That's my php code :

```php
add_action('wp_ajax_country_search', 'country_search_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_country_search', 'country_search_callback');

function country_search_callback()
{
    header("Content-Type: application/json");

     $args_pays = array(
        "post_type" => 'pays',
        "posts_per_page" => 50,
    );

    $args_tarif = array(
        "post_type" => 'tarif',
        "posts_per_page" => 50,

    );

    $tarifs = get_posts($args_tarif);

    $countries = get_posts($args_pays);
    if ($countries);
    if ($tarifs) {
        foreach ($countries as $country) :
            setup_postdata($country);
            $country_names[] =
                get_the_title($country);
            $country_zones[] = get_field('pays_id_zone', $country);
        endforeach;
        foreach ($tarifs as $tarif) :
            setup_postdata($tarif);
            $tarif_zone[] =
                get_field('tarif_dans_id_zone', $tarif);
            $tarif_type[] = get_field('tarif_type', $tarif);
            $tarif_sens[] = get_field('tarif_sens', $tarif);
            $tarif_vers[] = get_field('tarif_vers_id_zone', $tarif);
            $tarif_in[] = get_field('tarif_de_id_zone', $tarif);

        endforeach;
        $premiere_cle[] = array_fill_keys($tarif_zone, $country_zones);
        $deuxieme_cle[] = array_fill_keys($country_zones, $tarif_type);
        $troisieme_cle[] = array_fill_keys($tarif_type, $tarif_sens);
        $quatrieme_cle[]  = array_fill_keys($tarif_sens, array($tarif_vers, $tarif_in));

    };

    echo json_encode($premiere_cle);
wp_die()
}
```

With this code, I get the following JSON object:

```
[{"A":["D","E","B","C","B","B","A","A","Z"],"C":["D","E","B","C","B","B","A","A","Z"],"E":["D","E","B","C","B","B","A","A","Z"],"B":["D","E","B","C","B","B","A","A","Z"],"":["D","E","B","C","B","B","A","A","Z"]}]
```

How can I combine all the different arrays, which now all have a value that should be the key of the other, if you see what I mean?

In the end, I'm trying to recreate something like this: https://www.orange.be/fr/options-et-services/international-roaming/tarifs

All help will be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: WP_Query probably isn't the way to go here. You might consider using `get_posts()` instead. Get all the `pays` posts, put them in an array, and then for each of those, then use `get_posts` to set the `tariff` post type posts as a sub-array.

Comment: Can't tell from your example, whether all those `tarif_zone X` entries below each country are exactly the same (looks hat way), or if you need to get different ones for each country ...? But the code doesn't look like there was any specific association between the two that you would be checking on in any way. So if they are all the same - then I would create that sub-array first, and then in your loop over the countries, simply add it to your result structure under each country key.

Comment: Hello! Thanks both of you for your help! I updated my question because I still can't figure out an answer!

Comment: _"How can I combine all the different arrays, which now all have a value that should be the key of the other, if you see what I mean?"_ - no, I don't. I still can't really tell, what you actually want here. Even the way you gather your data to begin with here - "parallel" in _multiple_ arrays, instead of in one two-dimensional one, doesn't make much sense to me here.

Comment: I think you should first of all put your tarif data into an array - and use the zone identifier as key. So that would be something like `['A' => ['out' => ..., 'in' => ..., ...], 'B' => [...], ...]`. And then when you loop over your countries, you simply _pick_ the correct entries from that array, using the zone identifiers you have stored for that country.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you have a tip for me on how to gather the data in one two-dimentional array?